# Site running without an EC2 instance on AWS

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have been doing a lot technical troubleshooting and research, regarding AWS(Amazon Web Services) hosting of an organization website on a remote webserver, The organization deployed a wordpress website running on domain hosting service(Route 53),the site is running but am not seeing any instance on EC2 which might be associated to it.However,the person who deployed the site, is saying that the site is running on an instance, but I have not seen it on the listings of EC2

Could this mean that the site might be running without EC2 instance associated to it, besides being a dynamic site?
After long hours figuring out on how I can access the site files(backend)..but nothing of help, I have decided to post this question here.

Comment: Lightsail instances do not show in the normal EC2 console.

Comment: @hardillb  ,Thanks for your feedback. How do they show or how can I access them?

Comment: @hardillb , I have just checked in LightSail, but still no instance associated with the site!

Comment: First, check if the DNS is pointed to an Amazon-owned IP. It's possible the instance is at a nother host and only Route 53 is being used at AWS. After that, check your AWS billing; it'll be broken down by service and region. There are many regions and services and it can be hard to find the right one at times.

Comment: Check other regions. The mains ways to run Wordpress in AWS is EC2 / Lightsail. It'd be nice to run it in lambda but that doesn't work yet.

Comment: @Tim ,If you saying that the main ways to run wordpress in AWS is EC2/Lightsail ,I have checked and verified both sides but there's no instance existing..yet the site is running(live online)

Comment: @ceejayoz  ,I have checked the DNS,and is rightfully pointed to an Amazon-owned IP.However,if i may ask,is it possible that an instance can possibly be hosted on another machine or hosting service besides AWS and still be pointing to or associated with the site remotely...i thought this could only be possible within AWS due to security!

Comment: Now that you've confirmed the IP is an Amazon IP, you should check the AWS account's billing section. Find which region has EC2 spending and switch to that in the EC2 console.

Comment: If you want for the help please share both the domain name and the screenshot of route 53

Comment: Also, did you check every region? AWS has 25 regions, you would have to check them individually. Alternately check the billing console / cost explorer which would help narrow things down, as AWS is very good at billing for resources used.

Comment: @Tim ,You right..I have checked out region by region and  by luck I landed on it...being in a far different region. Thanks to you guys.

Comment: @ceejayoz ,Thanks a lot, the instance has been in a different region.

Comment: @ceejayoz ,I just analyzed the instance but it's status check indicates red "Instance reachability check failed" and right now the site is not running.

Answer (score 2):

I will answer this so you can accept the answer and close the question off.

A good approach to finding resources in AWS is to use the [AWS cost explorer](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/aws-cost-explorer/). Any resources in any region will show on the bill. You may have to use search to find out what the entries / lines mean but it's not difficult. For example I recall APS2 is short for "Asia Pacific Southeast 2", ie Sydney.

As suggested above, check for EC2 and Lightsail instances in each region. A Route53 hosted zone can be created in any region and it makes little difference as it's a global resource. The EC2 instance has to be created in the region you want the server to be in, which affects latency.